# c# recursive function not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, function, recursion

I trying to make recursive function but I get this error: **not all code paths return a value** I know why I get this error its because the `if` not returning something but I don't want it to return something... How to bypass this error? (It should really be just warning)

```
    private double calculate(double money, int months)
    {
        months--;
        if (months != 0)
            calculate(profit * 0.3, months);
        else
            return profit;
    }
```

Edit: I call it like that when user click the button

```
    private void bCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        profit = double.Parse(tbMoney.Text);
        months = int.Parse(tbMonth.Text);
        tbPpofit.Text = calculate(profit,months+1).ToString();
    }
```

If I write return like you say it will not give the result that i need

Comment: `I don't want it to return something` but your function **must** return a double,

Comment: You probably want `return calculate(profit * 1.3, months);` but we have to guess. And of course recursion isn't the best approach here.

Comment: You do not recursion to do this calculation.

Comment: Ok than you guys.. I will do something else.

Comment: I agree with Maarten.  There is a non-recursive solution to this problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply add a return to the recursive branch:

```
  if (months != 0)
        return calculate(profit * 0.3, months);
  ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a `return` value to your code for recursion:

```
  if (months != 0)
        return calculate(profit * 0.3, months);
```